# Struts 2.5.8 and Tiles 3.0.7: Unable to load the resources like img, css and js inside the JSP pages

Tags: struts2, tiles-3

I recently upgraded my application to Struts 2.5.8 and Tiles 3.0.7. I also have upgraded to Spring v4.3.4, but its not integrated with tiles. I am able to start my application properly without any errors until now.

I see all the `struts.xml` and `tiles.xml` files are loaded properly and are being rendered correctly. However, when I open the first (login) page, I see that it is not able to load the resources like CSS, JS and images which are present inside the webapp directory. I see no errors anywhere in the log files.

But, when I press F12 in the browser, I see the below error in the browser console:

```
Error1: Unable to load any resource
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Users/Public/Documents/FIXED/Rosy/JComponents/SALYExplorerWebApp/SALYExplorer/src/main/webapp/static/style/content.css
localhost:8485/SALYExplorer/static/javascript/javascript.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
localhost:8485/SALYExplorer/static/javascript/swap.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
localhost:8485/SALYExplorer/static/javascript/SALYExplorer-layout.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
localhost:8485/SALYExplorer/static/javascript/prototype.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
localhost:8485/SALYExplorer/static/pictures/utils/print.gif Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
localhost:8485/SALYExplorer/static/style/xtree_ext.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
localhost:8485/SALYExplorer/static/style/xtree.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
localhost:8485/SALYExplorer/static/pictures/proximus.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
localhost/:26 Uncaught ReferenceError: set_table_display is not defined
localhost:8485/SALYExplorer/static/style/xtree.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

F.e.
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/SALYExplorer/static/javascript/prototype.js
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 
Remote Address:[::1]:8080
Response Headers
view source
Content-Language:en
Content-Length:990
Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8
Date:Fri, 30 Dec 2016 18:17:39 GMT
Request Headers
view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:CONFIG=IU%3DYES%7CPA%3DYES%7CCA%3DYES%7CNA%3DYES%7CCN%3DYES%7CCI%3DYES%7CDI%3DYES%7CLI%3DYES%7CTI%3DYES%7CNI%3DYES%7CSI%3DYES%7CPM%3DYES%7CSU%3DYES%7CII%3DYES%7CVS%3DYES%7CVN%3DYES%7CSW%3DYES%7COS%3DYES; XTREE=28%3D1%7C39%3D1%7C89%3D1%7C31%3D1; username=id829957; logService=RRO_TEST; language=EN; authMethod=AUTH_LAM; JSESSIONID=61F12923C6E58695243E48B753DAFAFF
Host:localhost:8080
Referer:http://localhost:8080/SALYExplorer/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: Just change then name of your `static` folder, which holds resources, to some other name.

Comment: Woh...Thanks a lot Aleksandr M. You are a life saver to me :) It worked like a charm. So we cannot have keywords as directory names anywhere. But it was working before this upgrade. Anyways, thanks again and wish you a great New Year :)

Comment: @AleksandrM can please send it as an answer so this question could be marked as answered.

Comment: @AlirezaFattahi Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Struts2 the url-s beginning with the `/static` are for retrieving resources from the **classpath**.

Read more about static content handling in the [documentation](https://struts.apache.org/docs/static-content.html).

The simplest solution for your problem is to change the name of your folder that holds resources from `static` to something else.

Comment: @Vikd please mark it as correct, as you commented !